# Combine columns of text type to a jsonb column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with below structure in postgres where id is the primary key.

```
┌──────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
│              Column              │       Type       │ Collation │ Nullable │                           Default                            │ Storage  │ Stats target │ Description │
├──────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
│ id                               │ bigint           │           │          │                                                              │ plain    │              │             │
│ requested_external_total_taxable │ bigint           │           │          │                                                              │ plain    │              │             │
│ requested_external_total_tax     │ bigint           │           │          │                                                              │ plain    │              │             │
│ store_address.country            │ text             │           │          │                                                              │ extended │              │             │
│ store_address.city               │ text             │           │          │                                                              │ extended │              │             │
│ store_address.postal_code        │ text             │
```

I want to convert the `store_address` fields to a jsonb column.

```
┌──────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
│              Column              │       Type       │ Collation │ Nullable │                           Default                            │ Storage  │ Stats target │ Description │
├──────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
│ id                               │ bigint           │           │          │                                                              │ plain    │              │             │
│ requested_external_total_taxable │ bigint           │           │          │                                                              │ plain    │              │             │
│ requested_external_total_tax     │ bigint           │           │          │                                                              │ plain    │              │             │
│ store_address                    │ jsonb            │           │          │                                                              │ extended │              │             │
```

Any efficient of doing this?

Comment: And why would you want to denormalize the table that way, introducing all the possible problems that come with it?

Comment: that's a good question. I am trying to move the data from a dynamoDB table to a postgres table. At this point, a `jsonb` column type is more convenient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a new column, UPDATE the table and populating the new `jsonb` column. After that you can drop the old columns:

```
alter table the_table 
    add store_address jsonb;
    
update the_table
  set store_address = jsonb_build_object('country', "store_address.country", 
                                         'city', "store_address.city",
                                         'postal_code', "store_address.postal_code");
alter table the_table
  drop "store_address.country", 
  drop "store_address.city",  
  drop "store_address.postal_code"
```